# Как правильно сделать таблицу в БД без первичного ключа?

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет. Есть таблица в БД - `products`. У каждого продукта есть страна-производитель, для нормализации БД, сделал таблицу `countries`, где есть поля `id` и `name`. Далее, делаю таблицу М:М - `products_has_countries`, где мне нужно хранить в каждой записи id продукта и id страны, чтобы их связать. Вопрос: можно ли не создавать поле с primary key?

Comment: почему вы не хотите создавать первичный ключ ? У вас же наверняка есть требование не сохранять связь одной страны с одним продуктом более одного раза. А раз так то у вас есть диктуемый самой природой данных первичный ключ, состоящий из этих двух полей (`primary key(id-продукта,id-страны)`). И да, никаких дополнительных полей разумеется не надо

Comment: @Mike было неправильное представление баз данных, из-за чего не понимал толком, что такое первичный ключ и что он может состоять из 2 столбцов.

Comment: А зачем вам связь многие ко многим? У вас один и тот же продукт может быть произведен в разных странах? Может проще добавить в продукт столбец для страны?

Comment: @Андрей И дублировать продукты, производимые в нескольких странах? не очень идея, прямо скажем.

Comment: *можно ли не создавать поле с primary key?* Лучше создайте. По крайней мере, это гарантирует отсутствие записей-дубликатов - полагаться в этом вопросе на клиентскую логику не следует.

Comment: @Akina, ну я вообще-то об этом и спрашиваю - если один продукт не может производиться в нескольких странах, то и связь многие-ко-многим не нужна

Comment: @Андрей, Вы полагаете, что автор в вопросе сообщил неверные сведения о том, что связь продукт-страна имеет тип "много-ко-много"?

Comment: @Akina, автор написал только "У каждого продукта есть страна-производитель", ничего про тип связи в вопросе нет. "Далее, делаю таблицу М:М" - а нужна ли она?

Answer (score 1):

> Как правильно сделать таблицу в БД без первичного ключа?

Никак, т.к. в реляционный БД первичный ключ должен быть.
  Раз уж вы заговорили о нормализации, наличие ПК - требование 1-й нормальной формы.

> Вопрос: можно ли не создавать поле с primary key?

Можно, и даже нужно, не создавать дополнительное поле, а использовать имеющееся.

Вы, видимо, путаете первичный ключ и суррогатный ключ.

Суррогатный ключ (поле ID с автогенерацией) тут не нужен, т.к. в этой таблице уже есть хороший естественный первичный ключ - пара id-продукта, id-страны.

Answer (score 0):

21 век один и тот же продукт может производится в разных странах, например машины, процесоры.

Таблицу без первичного ключа создавать можно и в данном случаю он не нужен в класическом виде. Можно создать составной первичный ключ по 2м полям для исключения дублирования.

Answer (score -1):

Смотря что вам надо. Если `products_has_countries` это вспомогательная таблица со связями много ко многим, то конечно первичный ключ не обязателен.

Но мне кажется у ваших продуктов не могут быть по две страны производителя.
И `country_id` должен быть прямо в таблице `products`.